# All Tables Not Showing in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I have a major challenge this morning. I imported a mysql database using phpmyadmin. Besides the table it is showing the all no of tables in this format DatabaseName(407). When i clicked on the table, it listed only 97. What do you think is happening and what can i do to rectify the error.

Comment: Might it be permission-related?

Comment: Could you give us the status message that phpmyadmin shows once the upload has finished please and edit it into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is a big database it is possible that the import was incomplete. Check this option **Partial import**, which allows the interruption of an import in case the script detects it is close to the PHP timeout limit. This might be good way to import large files, however it can break transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once. In my case, no error would be printed, the page would just go blank. If it is the same problem, you might have a corrupted file. Check that your "file.sql" (or whatever document you are using for the import) correctly render table 97.